# Accessing Style setters in code

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to implement pinch/stretch zooming on a ListBox:

```
<ListBox
   Grid.Row="1"
   ManipulationCompleted="ListBox_ManipulationCompleted"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Paras}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <TextBlock
         DataContext="{Binding}"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Text="{Binding Text}"
         FontSize="{Binding FontSize}">
       </TextBlock>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

What I really want to do is bind a RenderTransform to a Zoom property of my ViewModel but that's not allowed. I can bind to the FontSize and it changes the FontSize correctly, but I have to hard code this in my code-behind. What I really want to do is honour the FontSize settings set by the designer and apply a uniform zoom to all the FontSizes. So in my code behind I have:

```
Style style = App.Current.Resources[_XElement.Name.LocalName] as Style;
if ( style != null )
{
  foreach ( var s in style.Setters )
  {
    Setter setter = s as Setter;
    if ( setter != null )
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(setter.Property + "=" + setter.Value);
    }
  }
}
```

I can't access setter.Property.Name (compile time error) although I can see it is FontSize is in the debugger. And Value is always "Could not evaluate expression" - outputs as blank.

Any clues, either as to what's going on here, or a better wayof doing it?

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access the `Name` because the Silverlight implemenation of `DependencyProperty` does not expose the name public.  In order to pickup the Setters that set the `FontSize` property you will need to use a little reflection to pick out of the `Style.TargetType` a static field called "FontSizeProperty" and extract its value.  Then compare each setter `Property` with that value if you have a match then you have found the setter reponsible for the `FontSize`.